# .NET Equivalent for VB6 DoEvents + Sleep

Tags: vb.net, vb6, sleep, doevents

I have a program that I'm updating from VB6 to VB.NET that is used for making optical measurements. The hardware runs Win XP or Win 2000 Embedded. In the original code, there is a section that is triggered after a measurement is started that uses DoEvents and Sleep:

```
While instDefItf.InstrumentState = Busy
  Sleep 500
  DoEvents
Wend
```

I've tried replacing the middle two lines in my code with a simple `Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)` (I realize that this is probably poor practice, but not having a ton of experience with VB, I was trying to preserve the VB6 program as closely as possible). This makes the code work correctly - on the second try. On the first try, the measurements that are supposed to be taken simply aren't, but no errors are thrown and the subsequent code executes correctly.

Based on this, I have two primary questions. First, is there something I could simply replace the VB6 code with to get the desired functionality? Second, is there a better way to periodically query the instrument state that doesn't make use of the `Sleep` function?

EDIT:

The function I referred to above is a helper function (I think that's the right term) that checks to see if the instrument has completed its measurement. The measurement routine is contained within a DLL, and the code that executes it is given below.

```
If cbMeasLength.Value = vbUnchecked Then
    Call I12001Ref.StartMtj1IlAcquisition2(CLng(lChannel), ConnectorA, m_moduleCollection.ReflectanceModule(lRm).SerialNumber)
End If

' Wait the measurement completion
If cbMeasLength.Value = vbUnchecked Then
    If WaitForOperationCompleted = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Comment: I guess you subscribed to something that put events in your MessageQueue (err ... was it called this back in the pre Win32 days?) that's why you needed the DoEvents (this was handling all/some(?) pending messages on the queue all on the same thread) - now this kind of multitasking/threading is long gone (maybe not on some Embedded systems but I doubt it) - so have a look at what kind of events you are subscribing and just handle those without any sleep - or better: **give us more details** (I'm kindof curios/interested)

Comment: btw: in modern VB there is something similiar with all UI *processes* running on a dedicated thread - so maybe you block this with your sleep - the common alternative is a Timer (can be asynch. in this case there are async-sleep primitives around)

Comment: and finally: if you really want to be pure to VB6 - there is still a [`DoEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) around

Comment: See the edit above. Incidentally, I tried using `DoEvents`, and it didn't have any effect. The strangest thing to me is that the code works correctly the second time it's called.

Comment: Does the 3rd-party component you are using to communicate with the hardware support events, or must it be polled?  Does the vendor of that that component offer a .NET or other version of their SDK?  If you are forced to use an ActiveX component (dll) for communicating, do you know if it is safe for multithreading, or are you stuck using it only on your UI thread?

Comment: Well, what do you know? There are some events that it appears the instrument can raise. I'll have to take a look at those. The product is discontinued and they aren't providing a .NET SDK. I actually have no idea if it's safe for multithreading. Is there a way to find out short of trying it?

Comment: Update: I tested the event, and the result makes me think I'm looking in the wrong place for the issue. If I try activating the reference routine and then triggering the "Finish" event before a reference has been taken, it will hang for 18+ minutes without doing anything. If I do the same after a reference has been taken (unsuccessfully) the event occurs after ~10 seconds, which makes me think something isn't initializing correctly.